# Protobuf-net Protogen generates DataFormat.TwosComplement for int32

Tags: protobuf-net, protogen

I'm using Protogen included in protobuf-net r580 to compile the following .proto file:

```
message TestMessage2 {
  required int32 someint = 1; 
}
```

And I found strange the resulting code use TwosComplement wire format:

```
Private _someint As Integer
<Global.ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired:=True, Name:="someint", DataFormat:=Global.ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)> _
Public Property someint As Integer
```

Instead of more optimized default varint type. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: As Jon notes, "int32" in a .proto schema is *required* to use the regular (non-zigzag) varint encoding, which is exactly what is happening here. If you want the zigzag varint encoding, specify "sint32". Either way, this is a varint. The only question is: is it zigzag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the behaviour which matches the "core" protobuf documentation. From the ["More Value Types"](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#types) section:

> **Signed Integers**
>
> As you saw in the previous section, all the protocol buffer types associated with wire type 0 are encoded as varints. However, there is an important difference between the signed int types (sint32 and sint64) and the "standard" int types (int32 and int64) when it comes to encoding negative numbers. If you use int32 or int64 as the type for a negative number, the resulting varint is always ten bytes long – it is, effectively, treated like a very large unsigned integer. If you use one of the signed types, the resulting varint uses ZigZag encoding, which is much more efficient.

The "default varint type" is the *inefficient* wire format for values which may well be negative.

As per the docs, use `sint32` to use ZigZag encoding.

Basically, it looks to me like protobuf-net is behaving absolutely correctly.